# Defining several multicolumns in a row

Tags: tables, multicolumn

For example, I may produce the following scheme:

```
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
| D | E | F | G | H | I |
```

Two columns (D, E and F, G and H, I) in second row must be a half size of columns in first row (D = 1/2 of A, E = 1/2 A and so on). 
But when I use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}` it merges also with `C` column and column `D` is small.

Give me a latex code, please.

Comment: May be you are starting with `&` the sfirst row before the multicolumn command and if so, this is your mistake...

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please show us what you try so far! probably you have some error in code

Comment: I'm not starting with `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce what you're saying. Does this work on your machine?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C}\\
D & E & F & G & H & I
\end{tabular}
\\[2cm]


With a fixed width:

\begin{tabularx}{6cm}{|>{\centering}p{1cm}|>{\centering}p{1cm}|>{\centering}p{1cm}|>{\centering}p{1cm}|>{\centering}p{1cm}|>{\centering}p{1cm}|}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C}\\
D & E & F & G & H & I
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C}\\ ` instead to avoid the shifted vertical line after 'A' and 'E'?

Comment: @leandris Yes. Thanks! (The purpose of this post was just to find out why LaTeX seems to behave in an unexpected way.)

Comment: You should use at least one `X` column in a `tabularx`.

Comment: @Bernard Yes. Thanks! Again, this post is only to demonstrate that there is no problem with `\multicolumn` whatsoever.